# Determine the dimension of the range and determine the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If instead it had said: A basis $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ with

$g(v_1)=(1,0,1)$, $g(v_2)=(0,1,0)$, $g(v_3)=(\frac12, 0, \frac12)$

I could easily solve it, but I don't know how to handle this situation. Any hints?

**Edit**

Since I am not really good at explaining these things, I think I'm just going to post a picture of the actual problem. I'm having trouble with c).

[image]

Comment: Do you know anything about $V$?

Comment: I’ve edited my question and added some missing details.

Comment: It’s impossible for $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ to be a basis for $V$ and to also have $g(1,0,1)=v_1$ and $g(1/2,0,1/2)=v_3$. The latter implies that $v_1=2v_3$.

Comment: Okay, so the kernel only consists of the zero vector, because there is a contradicition, and that implies that the dimension of the range is 3?

Comment: The picture is different from what you copied: the third vector that appears in the question is $(1/2,0,-1/2)$, not $(1/2,0,1/2)$. Like @amd was saying, without this minus sign $g$ can't exist and it doesn't make sense to ask about its kernel.

Comment: Wow, I really messed up this thing badly right from the get-go. But I am still unsure about what I am supposed to do in order to solve this problem. The picture is the correct problem statement.

Comment: I guess that by “proper vector” the text means nonzero. IMO the zero vector _is_ a “proper” vector—you can’t have a vector space without it!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $g$ sends a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to linearly independent vectors in $V$. Hence $g$ must be one-one. (Verify this fact!) If $g$ is one-one, what is $\ker g$? If you've determined this, what is $\text{im } g$?

Comment: I don't really know how to understand your hint, what do you mean g is one-one? I attempted to answer the problem myself (look above your post). Is it a correct procedure?

Comment: I have researched a bit, and haven't found a really explicit post that says, "if g sends a basis of V to linearly independent vectors in V, then g must be one-one.

Comment: @Carl nonetheless try proving the fact if $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces with $\dim V \le \dim W$ and $T:V\to W$ is linear transformation which sends a basis of $V$ to a set of linearly independent vectors of $W$ then $T$ is one-to-one. This follows from the basic properties of vector spaces and linear transformations.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt of answering my own question.

What if I arrive at an expression for $g(1,0,0)$ $g(0,1,0)$ and $g(0,0,1)$ in terms of $v$?

$g(1,0,0) = \frac12v_1+v_3$

$g(0,1,0) = v_2$

$g(0,0,1) = \frac12v_1-v_3$

If I then obtain a mapping matrix for it:

$$ A= \left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2}&0&1\\0&1&0\\\frac{1}{2}&0&-1\end{matrix}\right) $$

Can I use this for anything?

Comment: Well, once you have a matrix for the transformation, how would you go about finding the range (column space) and kernel (null space)? However, you needn’t go to all this trouble. You should be able to solve part (c) from basic properties of linear transformations and vector spaces (see [Ashish K’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3422948/265466)).